# How to fix DOMException error in google chrome?

Tags: html, typescript, google-chrome

I work with sounds in a browser game. I wrote sound manager. everything works fine, but not in Google chrome. I handled the error "uncaught (in promise) domexception", after the sounds were played in 50 percent of cases, in other cases it returns the error DOMException. What could be the problem?

```````````````
export class AudioFile{
    private audio: HTMLAudioElement;
    private fileMP3: string;
    private fileOGG: string;
    private volume = 1;
    private loop = false;
    constructor(MP3:string, OGG:string) {
        this.audio = new Audio();
        this.fileMP3 = MP3;
        this.fileOGG = OGG;
        this.audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? this.audio.src = this.fileMP3 : this.audio.src = this.fileOGG;
        this.audio.load();
        this.audio.volume = this.volume;
        this.audio.loop = this.loop;
    }
    public play() {
        this.audio.currentTime = 0;
        const playPromise = this.audio.play();
        if (playPromise !== undefined) {
            playPromise.then(_ => {
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
    public stop() {
        this.audio.pause();
    }
}
``````````````sound manager`````````````
export class SoundManager {
    private sounds = new Map();
    private static _soundManager: SoundManager;
    constructor(){
        if (SoundManager._soundManager) {
            throw new Error("Instantiation failed: "+
            "use Singleton.getInstance() instead of new.");
        }
        SoundManager._soundManager = this;
    }
    public static get instance(): SoundManager {
        if (this._soundManager)
            return this._soundManager;
        else
            return this._soundManager = new SoundManager();
    }
    preload() {
        const pathMP3 = SoundConfig.PATHMP3;
        const pathOGG = SoundConfig.PATHOGG;
        for (const item in SoundConfig.SOUNDS) {
            const name = SoundConfig.SOUNDS[item].NAME;
            this.sounds.set(name, new AudioFile(pathMP3 + name + '.mp3', pathOGG + name + '.ogg'));
        }
    }
    getSound(id: string): AudioFile {
        return this.sounds.get(id);
    }
}
```````````````

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. There's almost certainly more information in the error than the word "DOMException", and you really don't want guesses for answers.. Why don't you post ***all*** of the error information, line numbers, stack trace etc with your question, to help us help you on your way?

Comment: `console.log(error); //DOMException` 
Error don't have any information, only string "DOMException".   :`(

Comment: Can you place a breakpoint on that `console.log(error);` and tell us a little more about what `error` actually is?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you spendr.

`error: DOMException
code: 0
message: "play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`

Game runs through the iframe and I was needed to add a feature policy for autoplay.

`<iframe src="..." allow="autoplay">`

The [article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) that helped me in solving the problem

Comment: Glad to help. Have an upvote for bothering to come back and self-answer. This is sure to be useful to someone in the future.